# Add remote server path to environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables

A very (I thought) simple question, but cannot find an answer:

In Bash:
**Is it possible to add the path to a remote server to an environment variable?**

Use case:
We are setting up a local `pip` repo and want to set the rc file’s path as an env var on the client nodes, however the rc file is on our Git server.

For example:

```
//gitservername:/install/pip
```

However, the colon also used in the path, is the value separator in the specified env var, `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`.

[Documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use `autofs`. Export the target directory (which you want to add in path) via NFS, install `autofs` package. And then you can add in variable:

```
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/net/githostname/path/to/directory
```

You can use of course plain NFS (autofs just hide the actual NFS operations). This way you will have the filesystem mounted on boot (if this is your desire). Because `autofs` do the things on request and you can have delays and see the problem late (as opposite of NFS where you see the problem on the process of mounting filesystem)

Comment: Thank you for the insight and comments regarding NFS (on the deleted answer).  It's opened my eyes to the wonder that is NFS and made mounting the NAS and non-NAS disks *so* much easier. I'm an  analytical utilities programmer, and (obviously!) very new to this side of the world. My end solution was purely NFS based. Thank you.